# Dodge Ram 1500 SLT 4.7 Losing Coolant

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, dodge, ram

I have a 2003 Dodge Ram 1500 with a 4.7 magnum, and I have replaced the radiator, thermostat and water pump. I keep having to fill the reservoir every couple of days. Fluid keeps coming out of the over flow tube. Any suggestions on what could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Coolant coming out of the overflow is a sign of over-pressurisation. The cheapest cause of this is the pressure cap failing - have you replaced that?

The other main causes of it are overheating, or gas getting into the system and so increasing the pressure, usually through a head gasket breach between a cylinder and the water jacket.

Have you noticed any signs of overheating? If not, it might be worth doing a compression test on the cylinders to look for signs of a head gasket blow.